# Count number of unique elements at index in 2D list

Tags: python, list, count

Given list:

```
a = [["b", "a", 3], ["a", "b", 4], ["y", "a", 2], ["b", "a", "b"]]
```

I want to produce a 2D list of unique elements at index [1] and their count. Executing on list a would produce:

```
[["a", 3], ["b", 1]]
```

I've gotten as far as writing this code:

```
[(item[1], sum(x[1].count(item[1]) for x in a)) for item in a]
```

...however, it produces the list:

```
[('a', 3), ('b', 1), ('a', 3), ('a', 3)]
```

I'd love to solve it using a one liner if possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get a set from your code which would provide just unique entries

```
a = [["b", "a", 3], ["a", "b", 4], ["y", "a", 2], ["b", "a", "b"]]
set([(item[1], sum(x[1].count(item[1]) for x in a)) for item in a])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are looping over all sub-lists and preserve the count of the second item within the whole list which certainly would produce the duplicate result for same items. Instead, you can use `zip()` function to get the second column and then use `collections.Counter` to count the number of items within second column:

```
In [3]: from collections import Counter

In [5]: Counter(zip(*a)[1]).items()
Out[5]: [('a', 3), ('b', 1)]
```

In python 3.X:

```
z = zip(*a)
next(z)
Counter(next(z)).items()
[('a', 3), ('b', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) combining with [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions), you can get counts of items:

```
>>> a = [["b", "a", 3], ["a", "b", 4], ["y", "a", 2], ["b", "a", "b"]]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(item[1] for item in a)  # gen-expr to yields 2nd ([1]) items
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 1})
```

To get result as a list of sequences:

```
>>> Counter(item[1] for item in a).most_common()
[('a', 3), ('b', 1)]
>>> [list(x) for x in Counter(item[1] for item in a).most_common()]
[['a', 3], ['b', 1]]
```